# Spinner invisível no formulário

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário onde adicionei o spinner, o código deu tudo certo, já consegui adicionar e pegar o item selecionado, o problema está na visibilidade do spinner. Ele só aparece na tela quando clico em cima, e logo depois que escolho a opção ele volta a ficar invisível. Já fiz de tudo e não acho o erro. [image: erro]

[image: erri]

Aqui está o xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/endereco"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:theme="@style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp" />
```

E a classe do formulário:

```
public class Reclame extends Cronograma implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

Spinner option;
Button btnSend;
EditText Nome;
EditText Message;
EditText Endereco;
EditText Telefone;
EditText Email;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reclame, container, false);



    Nome = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nome1);
    Message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.msg);
    Endereco = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.endereco);
    Telefone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
    Email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnSend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send);
    option = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    option.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.option, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    option.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            String nome = Nome.getText().toString();
            String message = Message.getText().toString();
            String matricula = Endereco.getText().toString();
            String telefone = Telefone.getText().toString();
            String assunto = option.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String ema = Email.getText().toString();
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"marcos@wfprojetos.com.br"});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, assunto);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Nome: " +nome +'\n'+  "Endereço: "+matricula + '\n'+ "Telefone: "+telefone + '\n'+ "E-mail: "+ema + '\n'+ '\n'+message);


            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Selecione o serviço de e-mail:"));
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView mtext = (TextView) view;
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Você selecionou: "+mtext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Como faço pra corrigir este problema?

RAMARAL fiz o que sugeriu e ficou assim:
[image: er]

Comment: Eu acho que seria melhor expor também o código que tem relativo a isto

Comment: Retire `android:background="#ffffff"` ou mude para `android:background="#000000"`

Comment: Aproveitando o gancho Miguel, como deixo meu formulário com um tema mais atrativo? Estou achando ele meio "morto". Já vi formulários mais bem feitos poraií.

Comment: O problema está em que a cor da font do spinner é branca. Você tem algum *custom* style aplicado?

Comment: Tenho nao ramaral

Comment: Ja foi resolvido? Podes mostrar o xml do layout do formulário?

Comment: Foi resolvido sim. Era que estava com a mesma cor do background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prezado,

É altamente recomendável você utilizar o AppCompatSpinner ao invés do Spinner default, por diversas razões de compatibilidade. Porém o que deve estar errado é o estilo de exibição e por isto está aparecendo de maneira esquisita. Em um dos meus códigos, encontrei um trecho que pode te ajudar. Veja se ajuda:

```
private void popularSpinnerClassificacao(final TipoAtendimento tipoAtendimento){
        String[] arrayClassificacoes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.classificacao_atendimento);
        if(tipoAtendimento.equals(TipoAtendimento.LEADS)){
            arrayClassificacoes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.classificacao_atendimento_leads);
        }

        adapterClassificacao = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayClassificacoes);
        adapterClassificacao.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnClassificacao.setAdapter(adapterClassificacao);
        spnClassificacao.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Mateus obrigado pela ajuda, voce poderia me ajudar nesse outro problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131295/problemas-com-o-layout-da-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-diversos-celulares/131316#131316  ??